# $\dim M_p+\dim R/p\leq\dim M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Then, $\dim R_p+\dim R/p\leq\dim R$ for $p\in\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.

Under the additional assumption that $R$ is Noetherian, can we replace $R$ by a nonzero finitely generated $R$-module $M$ with $p\supset annM$ where $annM$ is the annihilator of $M$?

$\dim M_p+\dim R/p\leq\dim M$

Comment: I think it is true if $M$ is Noetherian $R$-module.. Have you checked this somewhere?

Comment: No I haven't, but this inequality seems necessary for my problem. And $M$ is indeed a module over a Noetherian ring $R$ under the problem. Could you please elaborate your thought?

Comment: Can you tell how you have tried...

Comment: The inequality holds when $M$ is finitely generated and $p \in Supp M$.

Comment: @user682705 Why $\dim R/p$ and not $\dim M/pM$ (if you really want an analogous to the first inequality)?

Comment: I just edited the post and in my question, R doesn't have to be local and $p⊃annM$. Then it seems true by definition. Thank you very much for the suggestions.

Comment: @user682705 In this case, $\dim R/p=\dim M/pM$.

Comment: Yes. Then, since $ann(M/pM)=\sqrt{annM+p}=\sqrt{p}=p$,  $\dim R/p=\dim M/pM$ and the inequality is analogous to the first one. I didn't catch that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and $p \in {\rm Supp}\, M$. Set ${\dim}_{R_p} M_p=t$ and ${\dim} \, R/p=s$. Then there exists a strict chain of primes in ${\rm Supp }_{R_p} M_p$: 
$$p_0R_p \subset p_1R_p \subset \dots \subset p_tR_p=pR_p.$$
On the other hand we have a strict chain of primes in ${\rm Spec}\, R/p$:
$$p/p=q_0/p \subset q_1/p \subset \dots \subset q_s/p. $$
Thus there exists a strict chain of prime of length $s+t$ in ${\rm Supp \, M}$:
$$p_0 \subset p_1 \subset \dots \subset p_t \subset q_1 \subset \dots \subset q_s $$
 which shows that $s+t \leq {\rm dim}\, M.$

Comment: Does $p\supset annM$ imply $p\in SuppM$, that is, $M_p\neq 0$?

Comment: If $M$ is finitely generated, then that is true.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your answer and comments.

Answer (score 2):

> **Definition:** Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then $dim M = dim (R/ann(M) )$ if $M \ne 0$ and $dim M = -1$ 
>   if $M = 0$.

Set $R:=\mathbb{Z} $, $p=\{0\}$ and $M:=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. Then $ann(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})=0 $ and $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})_p\cong \mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. Hence, $ann((\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})_p)=0$. And we have

$$dimM_p+dim(R/p)=dimR/annM_p+dimR/0=dim\mathbb{Z}+dim\mathbb{Z}=1+1=2\not\leq dimM=dimR=dim\mathbb{Z}=1.$$

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is not local.

Comment: Isn't $dimM_p$ $dim(R_p/annM_p)=dim\mathbb{Q}/0=dim\mathbb{Q}=0$?